# Dismiss loading in Ionic 2

Tags: android, angular, typescript, ionic2

So in my app I have a button that when clicked opens WhatsApp and sends a sound. On this button, I have attached a method that when the button is clicked it creates an Ionic loading component. The problem I am having is on the "loading.dismiss()". I wanted to make it so that when the WhatsApp is launched the loader is dismissed.

I have tried using ionViewWillLeave but it does not work because Ionic does not recognize my app opening WhatsApp as "leaving".

**soundboard.html** (button with click method)

```
<button ion-button (click)="share(sound.file)"></button>
```

**soundboard.ts**

```
loading = this.loadingCtrl;

public share(file: string): void {
    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
  });
    loading.present();
    SocialSharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(null, null, file);
    this.turnoff(loading) /* calls the loading.dismiss */
 }

ionViewWillLeave(loading) {
   loading.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/#shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver), your function returns a promise. I would do the dismissing in `then` and/or `catch`.

```
  SocialSharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(null, null, file)
    .then(res=>{
        loading.dismiss();
      }).catch(err=>{
        loading.dismiss();
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks suraj! could you tell me how ".then" works. Or point me to the doc for this

Comment: They are promises.. return value asynchronously..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: could you please take a look at this question, its related
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43967708/spinner-no-hidding-on-function

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using the SocialSharing plugin.
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin
 You can pass a success callback to the shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(), and call the loading.dismiss() in it.

Copied from the doc:

```
<button onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.shareViaWhatsAppToReceiver(receiver, 'Message via WhatsApp', null /* img */, null /* url */, function() {console.log('share ok')})">msg via WhatsApp for Addressbook ID 101</button>
```

Comment: you are right if OP was using the plugin directly.. This is ionic native wrapper though..just saying