# Ionic spinner not hidding on function "then"

Tags: android, angularjs, typescript, ionic2

I have a button that when clicked plays an audio and hides the loading spinner.
I am using `this.play().then` to hide the spinner. What I find weird is that this code works on my browser when I test it but it does not work on an actual device, I get the error below.

**soundboard.ts**

```
play(sound) { 
   sound.spinner = 'crescent'  
   console.log(sound)
 if(this.media) {
   this.media.pause();
 }
   this.media = new Audio(sound.file);
   this.media.load();
   this.media.play().then(res=>{
    sound.spinner = 'none';
    console.log('play');
  }).catch(err=>{
    sound.spinner = 'none';
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

**soundboard.html**

```
<ion-card-content (click)="play(sound)">     
  <div class="wrapper">
  <ion-spinner name="{{ sound.spinner }}"></ion-spinner>
  <img src="{{ sound.imageUrl }}" />
  </div>
</ion-card-content>
```

**error log**

```
"Cannot call method 'then' of undefined"
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems like [`play()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/media/#play) method doesn't return a promise and your code is expecting promise..

Comment: But how come it works in the browser?... using  `ionic serve -l`

Comment: If you use Chrome or Firefox turn on latency to mimic a delay... Locally the object is probably in place right away, while deployed it will take somewhat longer... Also, did you check the load function actually loading the soundfile?